# GitHub or BitBucket?

Tags: git, mercurial, github, cvs, bitbucket

I would like to host my code in the cloud. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: This is somewhat subjective and vague.  You seem to be conflating git vs. mercurial with github vs. bitbucket?

Comment: What sort of code are you going to manage? How many people are going to be involved? Is your code open source? Will it be developed by people with Windows? Will it be developed by people with Linux? Mac OS? How big is your code base?

Comment: They are both excellent. Use whatever the people around you use.

Comment: @John: maybe i'm conflating git vs mercurial, in that case, which you recommend me??

@nmichaels: in some case my code is opensource and another is privative, developed in Linux, Mac not in Windows

@Greg: Thanks!

Comment: In case you want to decide between Mercurial and Git, there are plenty of related questions here on SO. A simple search should help out.

Comment: thanks, i going to search and learn a little bit more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024483/comparing-the-pros-and-cons-of-bitbucket-to-github

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071215/build-ci-sdlc/bitbucket-vs-github-which-project-host-has-the-most.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Neither GitHub nor Bitbucket are SCMs -- they are just hosting services built around Git and Mercurial, which are the underlying SCMs. If your question is actually whether you should use Git/Mercurial as an SCM, then most people will answer "yes", but it sounds like you should read up on exactly what these are before diving in, since it sounds like you have quite a bit of confusion on the topic.

Comment: Just wanted to an important part on choosing an hosting service. github is well known for open source projects, but bitbucket provides the same functionality with as an extra FREE private repos. I' m not affiliated with Atlassian, but the FREE part made me choose for bitbucket.

Comment: Note: the free private repositories can only be shared with 5 people total - that includes all private repos you are in, and includes you.

Comment: @DaanWilmer, I had shared a private repo with 6 users. They have a good promotion system: if you invite people to join BitBucket, you get up to 3 additional places for repository users.

Comment: gitlab is another option now. As per this page https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/ they support unlimitted public and private repositories for free.